# node.js how to put a enter

Tags: node.js, logging

i am trying to code something in node.js but i don't know how to put a space for my log script:

```
Hook.info("Logger",`app: ${appopen}`)
```

what i want it to look like:

app: netflix

other app open: notepad

but i don't know how to put an enter so it looks like that.

so hopefully someone can help me with this!

also more information: im using https://jb3.github.io/webhook-discord/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Julien's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676799/node-js-how-to-put-a-enter/66676860#66676860) answer should be correct. I can't yet comment but be sure that you're using backticks since those are what you need for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It shouldn't be

```
Hook.info("Logger", "test \n ${appopen}"
```

but rather

```
Hook.info("Logger", `test \n ${appopen}`)
```

If you meant you wanted a carriage return at the end of the line then it should be

```
Hook.info("Logger", `test ${appopen}\n`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean a Carriage Return, I guess. Try `Hook.info("Logger", "\n")`

Comment: hello. i tried ```Hook.info("Logger", "test \n ${appopen}")``` but it then says: ```test
${appopen}``` with ${appopen} literally

Comment: Mhhh, you could try the html entity then `&#13;`? Are you viewing the text directly inside discord?

Comment: Julien, yes i am viewing it in discord